# How to export attribute table with start and end coordinates of lines to Excel?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, attribute-table, excel

I am working in QGIS. I have a georeferenced line layer and I want to export the attribute table and the coordinates of start and end points of my lines to Excel.

Can I do this with QGIS?

Comment: Reading the comments it seems you don't want to export the coordinate system but coordinates, please make sure your question reflects what you actually intend to do, otherwise it is tedious for people to answer properly.

Comment: Yes, You are right. Sorry! I want the coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Extract Nodes

A window will appears, choose a file to save and mark the option "Add result to canvas".

Right click in the new layer created and click on "save as".

Choose a name to your file and open it with a text editor to check the result.

Comment: thats was a great idea because thats create all the point that I have in my layer. In my layer, the line can have many ponts. But problem  is that still that doesn't issue the values of coordinate. Do I need any tools?

Comment: The coordinates should be the first and seccond columns, are you sure is not there?

Comment: Yes exg, the coordinate are in excel file. I didn't see in attribute table, thats why i wrote you. Still, do you know any way how to show the coordianates in the attribute table?

Comment: In the window openned when you right click "save as" in the layer to save as csv, select the option "add saved file to map". The layer created will have the coordinates in the atribute table.

Answer (score 12):

Extracting coordinates of start/end vertices (not all line vertices) from lines is a nice use case for new functionality in QGIS v.2.8, namely, the *function editor*.

This is the workflow:

1. Load your line layer to QGIS and activate it.
2. Open the field calculator and go to tab `Function Editor`.
3. Click on `New file`, write `vertices` as the new file name, and click on `Save file`.

   [image]
4. Copy the following code snippet *as is*, paste it into the `Function Editor` text area, and then click on `Run Script` and `Save file`:

   ```py
   from qgis.core import qgsfunction

   @qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
   def getStartVertexX(g, feature, parent): 
       return g.vertexAt( 0 )[0]

   @qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
   def getStartVertexY(g, feature, parent): 
       return g.vertexAt( 0 )[1]

   @qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
   def getEndVertexX(g, feature, parent): 
       line = g.asPolyline()
       return line[-1][0] if line else None

   @qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
   def getEndVertexY(g, feature, parent): 
       line = g.asPolyline()
       return line[-1][1] if line else None
   ```

   [image]
5. Go to tab `Expression` and do this:

   a. Check `Create a new field`.

   b. Set the output field name to `startX`, output field type to `real`, output field width to `12`, and precision to `6` (you may adjust these values if you consider it).

   c. Copy the following line into the `Expression` text area and then click on `OK`:

   ```
   getStartVertexX( $geometry )
   ```

   [image]
6. Repeat 5.a-c for fields `startY`, `endX`, and `endY`, with the following expressions, respectively:

   ```
   getStartVertexY( $geometry )
   getEndVertexX( $geometry )
   getEndVertexY( $geometry )
   ```
7. Save your edits.

   Now your line layer has field values for start and end coordinates from each corresponding line.

   [image]
8. Finally, as your requirement is to export the table to Excel, use the [XY Tools](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/xytools/) plugin as indicated in [How to export attribute table to Excel from QGIS?](http://bit.ly/1CIHEDT).

   [image]

That's it! Tell me if you face any issue.

**EDIT:** Steps 2 to 7 (!) can be avoided by using the following built-in QGIS functions in the Field Calculator:

- `$x_at(0)` For start X
- `$y_at(0)` For start Y
- `$x_at(-1)` For end X
- `$y_at(-1)` For end Y

Comment: In fact, I am working with Valmira 2.2.0. So the code that you gave me isn't correct in Valmira 2.2.0 .  But still, Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why not upgrading?

Comment: It is my boss that want to work with that programe?
I cann't do nothing! Anyway I find what i need so, thanks a lot from you.

Comment: @gcarrillo this is what I need. Only issue is that getEndVertexY($geometry) gives me an EvalError:Bad Index:2. Any ideas?

Comment: @gcarrillo Ah, I followed the screen capture and notice now that it's actually return line[-1][1] and not line[-1][2]

Comment: A great solution and very flexible. Long live to QGIS Function Editor!

Answer (score 3):

With QGIS 3 you can do for your respective fields:

```
x(  start_point( $geometry ))
y( start_point( $geometry ))
x( end_point( $geometry ))
y( end_point( $geometry ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Export table to excel:

1. Right click layer in table of contents select Save As
2. Under Format drop down select Comma Separated Value (CSV) option
3. Open excel and browse for saved .csv to open

Comment: Yes, but I want also the Coordinate system.
I have the line in layer, and I want also the coordina for the begins and the ends points.

Comment: Please update your question to make "begins and the ends points" more clear.

Comment: Sorry!
I want the X,Y coordinate for the firs point of the line, and I  Want the X,Y coordinate for the ends points of the line.

Answer (score 2):

For exporting the coordinates too, I assume you will have to add new columns for x and y coordinates and calculate these using the fieldcalculator with the appropriate operators.

Answer (score 1):

1) Click in Vector --> Geometry Tools --> Extract nodes
  2) In the new window  a)check "Add result to canvas"
                        b)Browse your locate and save with a name

3) Whait a moment, in the layer Right click and choose "Save as"
  4) In "Format" choose the "Comma Separated Values (.csv)"
  5) And open the .csv file in to Excel and you have all that you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding a figure further to miln40's solution above for QGIS 3. New users may find the solution easier to understand with a figure and more detail in the explanation.

Select the vector layer that has the line features. Open the field calculator from the data table. Check `Create New Field`, enter the name of the Field (e.g., Start_Lat), select `Decimal number (real)`.

[image: Field calculator showing expression to obtain start/end points on line]

You can vary your output field lengths and precision according to the type of coordinate system you are using. Output field length 12, and precision 6 was used in the example above, but I could have reduced these to length 7 and precision 1 in my example because I am working with UTM's. The 12 length and precision 6 will be needed if you are working in Lat/Long.