# Get Geometric Attribute Columns to Dynamically Update in QGIS

Tags: qgis, xy, dynamic

I want to add X Y columns to my point data shapefile. There are various ways to add them as explained here https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-adding-x-y-coordinate.

But none of these methods add a column that dynamically updates X Y values when a point location is changed. What I want to know is that is there any way to have geometric columns in QGIS ( X, Y, Length, Area) update dynamically?

Comment: If you're fine with a virtual field (that is, a field that won't be stored in your data source, but in your project), then @JGH's answer will work. If you need a permanent field for that, then this answer solves your question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/334345/4972

Answer (score 2):

You can create a virtual field, i.e. one that is always re-computed.

[image]