# QGIS calculate area automatically

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, area, calculate

Is there a way to calculate area automatically when I edit a polygon? I mean, is there any function there I can use on area field and update itself when I finish editing?

Comment: Create a virtual field and set the expression to `$area`, see the QGIS documentation : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-a-virtual-field

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

The `CalcArea2` plugin could be used to solve this problem.
Plugin [wiki](https://github.com/lmotta/calcarea2/wiki/English) and [homepage](https://github.com/lmotta/calcarea2).

Or as commented by [@J. Monticolo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/93097/j-monticolo) you could use auto field update functionality. Read this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/334345/35561) for more info.